# Entity Framework exclude archived records by default

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How can I configure Entity Framework to exclude archived records by default? Or in other words, add a filter or condition that applies to a table that will globally affect all usages of it.

Answer (score 3):

Applying Global Query filters is the way to go (it's not obvious from googling). This can be done inside the DbContext as per the Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

i.e. :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    // ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.Archived == false);
    //...
}
```

The nice thing about this is that a consumer can ignore these global query filters (as detailed in the article).

Comment: Please add a demonstration/code and not just a link to a page.